# Jackson : map nested object

Tags: java, jackson2

Using jackson, i wonder if it's possible du map json to Java with nested Object that are not like the json structure.

Here an exemple of what i want to do.

Json :

```
{
  a = "someValue",
  b = "someValue",
  c = "someValue"
}
```

Java :

```
public class AnObject {
  @JsonProperty("a")
  private String value;

  //Nested object
  private SomeObject;
}

public class SomeObject {
  @JsonProperty("b")
  private String value1;

  @JsonProperry("c")
  private String value2;
}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: It's not possible using annotations, but you can write your own deserializer, where you can manage Json like a Map and populate fields to pojo by yourself. https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html

Comment: @DmytroDovzhenko Pinging you to let you know that it indeed is possible, see my answer

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: That's not valid Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
private final SomeObject someObject;
```

which unwrappes all of `SomeObject`'s fields into the parent, resulting in the following when serializing:

```
{"a":"foo","b":"bar","c":"baz"}
```

Comment: I think it only work for Serializate, i want do Deserialize...
but i will give it a try

Comment: It also works for deserialization. I can give you a working example if you have trouble getting it to work

Comment: Effectivelyit work, even if the documentation only mention serialization. 

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to the world of wonky Jackson documentation :)

Comment: Is it possible to do this programmatically without using some annotation on a POJO? The codebase I m working on uses some sort of avro schema which generates pojo, which does not let me directly modify the pojo

Comment: yes, it is possible using Jackson MixIn feature

Answer (score 1):

Using ObjectMapper you can convert JSON string to Object.
Use [JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) in your AnObject class over someObject field.

```
@JsonUnwrapped
private SomeObject someObject;
```

then read JSON string and convert it to AnObject.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
   AnObject anObject1 = mapper.readValue(jsonString, AnObject.class);   
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a JSON object.

It's an [object literal](https://www.google.it/search?q=object%20literal).

Second of all, that is not a valid formatted object literal. 
The correct one is this:

```
{ "a" : "someValue", "b": "someValue", "c": "someValue"}
```

Next, as sayd in comments, you have to define your own deserializer.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    String json = "{\"a\" : \"someValue\",\"b\" : \"someValue\",\"c\" : \"someValue\"}";

    final ObjectMapper om =
        new ObjectMapper();//
    om.registerSubtypes(AnObject.class);
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(AnObject.class, new CustomDeserializer2());
    om.registerModule(module);

    AnObject ob = om.readValue(json, AnObject.class);
    System.out.println(ob.getValue());
    System.out.println(ob.getObject().getValue1());
    System.out.println(ob.getObject().getValue2());
}
```

Deserializer:

```
public class CustomDeserializer2 extends StdDeserializer<AnObject> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3483096770025118080L;

public CustomDeserializer2() {
    this(null);
}

public CustomDeserializer2(Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
}

@Override
public AnObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode interNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

    AnObject ob = new AnObject();

    if (interNode.get("a") != null) {
        ob.setValue(interNode.get("a").toString());
    }

    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();

    if (interNode.get("b") != null) {
        obj.setValue1(interNode.get("b").toString());
    }
    if (interNode.get("c") != null) {
        obj.setValue2(interNode.get("c").toString());
    }

    ob.setObject(obj);
    return ob;
}
```

Model: **Pay attention to @JsonProperty on A field**

```
public class AnObject {

@JsonProperty("a")
private String value;

private SomeObject object;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public SomeObject getObject() {
    return object;
}

public void setObject(SomeObject arg) {
    object = arg;
}



public class SomeObject {

private String value1;
private String value2;
public String getValue1() {
    return value1;
}
public void setValue1(String value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}
public String getValue2() {
    return value2;
}
public void setValue2(String value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}
```

Bye